# How to validate number in perl?

Tags: perl, numbers, validation

I know that there is a library that do that

> use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

yet I want to do it using perl regular expression. And I want it to work for double numbers not for only integers.

so I want something better than this

> $var =~ /^[+-]?\d+$/

thanks.

Comment: You know that deimal numbers could have an optional part (....)? after the integral part. You cou've tried a bit, at least.

Comment: i tried the one i put on my question and it did not work will when checking for a number like (3.5) as example.

Comment: It DID work - it told you correctly, that your pattern does not match the entire string "3.5"

Comment: im not that good on regular expression. do u have a better pattern?

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Perl

Comment: i assume you have a good reason not to use `Scalar::Util`

Comment: Why not use Scalar::Util? It's part of the STANDARD Perl library and thus is almost always available for programming use. Plus, Scalar::Util can handle "0 but true" which is a valid Perl number -- something your regular expression might not handle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Constructing a single regular expression to validate a number is really difficult. There simply are too many criteria to consider.  [Perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number/whole/integer/float?) contains a section "How do I determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float?

The code from that documentation shows the following tests:

```
if (/\D/)                          {print "has nondigits\n"      }
if (/^\d+$/)                       {print "is a whole number\n"  }
if (/^-?\d+$/)                     {print "is an integer\n"      }
if (/^[+-]?\d+$/)                  {print "is a +/- integer\n"   }
if (/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/)               {print "is a real number\n"   }
if (/^-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$/) {print "is a decimal number\n"}
if (/^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/) {
    print "is a C float\n"
}
```

- The first test disqualifies an unsigned integer.
- The second test qualifies a whole number.
- The third test qualifies an integer.
- The fourth test qualifies a positive/negatively signed integer.
- The fifth test qualifies a real number.
- The sixth test qualifies a decimal number.
- The seventh test qualifies a number in c-style scientific notation.

So if you were using those tests (excluding the first one) you would have to verify that one or more of the tests passes.  Then you've got a number.

Another method, since you don't want to use the module Scalar::Util, you can learn from the code IN Scalar::Util.  The looks_like_number() function is set up like this:

```
sub looks_like_number {
  local $_ = shift;

  # checks from perlfaq4
  return $] < 5.009002 unless defined;
  return 1 if (/^[+-]?\d+$/); # is a +/- integer
  return 1 if (/^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d+))?$/); # a C float
  return 1 if ($] >= 5.008 and /^(Inf(inity)?|NaN)$/i) 
           or ($] >= 5.006001 and /^Inf$/i);

  0;
}
```

You should be able to use the portions of that function that are applicable to your situation.

I would like to point out, however, that `Scalar::Util` is a core Perl module; it ships with Perl, just like `strict` does.  The best practice of all is probably to just use it.

Comment: The function you posted differs in output for input `looks_like_number('0 but true')`!

Comment: ...and for overloaded objects. Overloaded objects are handled in the latest release of Scalar::Util::PP. The PP version no longer exists in the latest dev release of the distro.

Comment: Yes, it appears that Scalar-List-Utils-1.23 had a pure Perl version, whereas Scalar-List-Utils-1.23_03 does not.  The reader could easily look up the source for v1.23 on CPAN, as that version does handle overloaded objects.  However, I fully believe that this dialogue serves to reiterate the point that it is foolish to try to build a new generalized number-qualifying solution out of regular expressions when Scalar::Util's looks_like_number() already exists; it's almost certain to be more robust, more modern, and more maintainable. Plus, it's part of the standard Perl distribution.

Comment: sub looks_like_number - this works really well. My parser was reading really odd nums that slipped through my standard check, like 5.23.14 or 2..6 or 1.-5  thanks!

Comment: @ski_squaw But unless you require a pure-Perl solution, Scalar::Util::looks_like_number is probably a better choice, and it's in the Perl core distribution.

Comment: @DavidO Scalar::Util looks like it would work. I had problems with installing some of the other packages mentioned in this post and similar posts on OSX (cpnam install tests failed)

Answer (score 6):

You should use Regexp::Common, most patterns are more complicated than you realize.

```
use Regexp::Common;

my $real = 3.14159;
print "Real" if $real =~ /$RE{num}{real}/;
```

However, the pattern is not anchored by default, so a stricter version is:

```
my $real_pat = $RE{num}{real};
my $real     = 3.14159;
print "Real" if $real =~ /^$real_pat$/;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Regexp::Common passes things that normal humans might consider a valid number syntax, such as: '1..2', '-1.0.2', and '1.-2'.  Another case supporting the point that the Scalar::Util approach is the best way.

Comment: @DavidO The documentation states that the match is not anchored.  Those patterns do not match a real number if anchored as shown there. They do match if unanchored.

Comment: Perhaps it would be reasonable to edit your post in keeping with the more robust regex: `m/^$RE{num}{real}$/`.  I haven't tested whether that would reject "`1.-2`" though.  BTW: I did ++ your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you should make sure that the number does not contain any commas so you do this:

> $var =~ s/,//g; # remove all the commas

Then create another variable to do the rest of the compare.

> $var2=$var;

Then remove the . from the new variable yet only once occurrence.

> $var2 =~ s/.//; # replace . with nothing to compare yet only once.

now var2 should look like an integer with no "."
so do this:

```
    if($var2 !~ /^[+-]?\d+$/){
        print "not valid";
    }else{
       #use var1 
    }
```

you can fix this code and write it as a function if you need to use it more than once.
Cheers!